# Ember Nested Route and Promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, promise

I have a jquery ajax call defined like this

```
var fetchMessages = function(){$.getJSON(<some url>).then(function(data){ return data; }};

var messages = fecthMessages();
```

My routes are setup like this

```
App.Router.map(function() {

    this.resource('messages', function() {
      this.resource('message', { path: ':message_id' });                       
    });                                                                        
  });
```

I use the promise `messages` in my routes like this

```
App.MessagesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function(){
        return messages;
    }
});
```

The above route works fine.

Next I have a nested route like shown below. This however errors out when I directly try to visit `#/messages/<id of the message>`. Loading `#/messages` followed by visiting `#/messages/<id of message>` works fine.

```
App.MessageRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
      message = messages.findBy("id", params.message_id);
      return message;

    }
  });
```

So how do I handle the promises in nested routes?

Comment: `fetchMessages` is not a function, you cannot execute it. | So ember can deal with a promise returned from `model()`? | Where is `findBy` defined?

Comment: Sorry, edited. `fetchMessages` is a function. `findBy` is a Ember thing. I'm basing things off this example code - https://github.com/tildeio/bloggr-client/blob/master/js/app.js

Comment: The purpose of `.then(function(data){ return data; }` is to strip `textStatus` and `jqXhr` arguments?

Comment: Nope. It does some data manipulation that I have skipped for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

> So how do I handle the promises in nested routes?

Apparently [Ember handles these for you](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/asynchronous-routing/).

> This however errors out when I directly try to visit #/messages/:
>
> ```
> App.MessageRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
>     model: function(params) {
>       message = messages.findBy("id", params.message_id);
>       return message;
>
>     }
>   });
> ```

`messages` is still a promise, not an array; it doesn't have a `findBy` method. Instead, use

```
return messsages.then(function(m) {
  return m.findBy("id", params.message_id);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I still have the issue that my view which relies on this promise/model and uses `this.get('context').model` is undefined when the view is rendered. Any idea how I make the view work with the promise too?

Comment: Hm, sorry, I don't have much experience with Ember.